# how to pass two lists in two dropboxes in one form

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to pass two lists(students and courses) from Controller to jsp file. It should be two dropboxes,  one form and one submit button. For now I can pass only one list.The idea is to choose student from one dropbox, several courses from another and submit for registration. Here is my Controller, two Classes: Student, Course and  jsp file. Thank you!

## Class Student

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
private int studentId;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@JoinTable(name="STUDENT_COURSE", joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID") })
private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();

public Student() {
}

public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Student(String name, Set<Course> courses) {
    this.name = name;
    this.courses = courses;
}


public int getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

## Class Course

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "COURSE_ID")
private int courseId;

@Column(name = "name")
private String courseName;

public Course() {
}

public Course(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
}

public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
}

public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
}

public int getCourseId() {
    return courseId;
}

public void setCourseId(int courseId) {
    this.courseId = courseId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Course{" +
            "courseName='" + courseName + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

## RegistrationController

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

@Autowired
private StudentService studentService;
@Autowired
private CourseService courseService;


@RequestMapping(value = "/register")
public String showRegister(Model model){

    Student student = new Student();
    Course course = new Course();
    model.addAttribute("student", student);
    model.addAttribute("course", course);
    List<Student> students = studentService.showAllStudents();
    model.addAttribute("students", students);
    List<Course> courses = courseService.showAllCourses();
    model.addAttribute("courses", courses);

    return "registration";
} .
```

## registration.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" 
uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>

<title>Spring MVC dropdown box</title>
```

```
<h2>Select student</h2>



<form:form  method="POST" action ="register" commandName="student">

    <table>

        <tr>

            <td>Please select:</td>

            <td><form:select path="name" >

                  <form:option value="" label="student" />

                  <form:options items="${students}" />

                   </form:select>

                          </td>

            <td><form:errors path="name" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" /></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>

        </tr>



    </table>

</form:form>
```

.

Comment: You can create another `<form:select` for the courses.

Comment: I tried it first, of course, but what do I do with a `commandName`?  If I choose student or course it throws exception.

Comment: I believe that we are using commandName to pass an object between controller and views. So how to pass two objects here?

Comment: I don't think you need to use `commandName`

Answer (score 0):

You can just create another `<form:select` for courses and delete `commandName` as you can send `students` and `courses` as HTTP Parameters which can be then retrieved from the `HTTPSerlvetRequest` object in your controller.

UPDATE: It's better that you create a simple `<form>` instead of a Spring `<form:form>` because this is just suitable when binding a form to a just one POJO in particular.

Comment: Thank you @alayor,  but I need to see those lists in drop boxes, so I need to pass them to jsp file from Controller. And if I remove `commandName` it  throws an exception.

Comment: Which exception is it throwing?

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute`, and again I'm not looking _to pass them to the controller_, I'm looking to pass them from the controller to the view form